# Missing the begin of the root in xml

Tags: c#, xml

The Code:

```
new XElement("Person"));
 XElement items = xdoc.Root
foreach (ObservableCollection<Person> x in list)
            {
                XElement children = new XElement("List");
                foreach (var person in x)
                {

                    XElement person = new XElement("Person",
                    new XElement("Name", person.name),
                    new XElement("Surname", person.surn),
                    new XElement("City", person.city));
                    items.Add(person);
                }
                items.Add(children);

            }
            xdoc.Save(path);
```

But in XML it looks like that:

```
<Pepole>
  <Person>
    <name>d</name>
    <surname>a</surname>
    <city>b</city>
  </Person>
  **<List />**
```

It's missing the start of the list - please any advice how to solve it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please, Add the XML format what you are getting and what you are expecting, Because looking at it it seems like you are adding List element at the end , but you want everything enclosed within List but question is not clear.

Comment: `items` and `xdoc` doesn't exist. Please show us complete codes pls

Comment: That's wird - I added the code in XML, but stack does not generate it
  XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
                     new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                     new XElement("Person"));
            XElement items = xdoc.Root;

Comment: i think you need children.Add(items); in that case and not items.Add(children);

then the XML will be

<Pepole>
 <List>
  <Person>
    <name>d</name>
    <surname>a</surname>
    <city>b</city>
  </Person>
 </List>
</Pepole>

Comment: If I do that, then the 'person' is not used, so the xml is empty :/

Answer (score 2):

Its very unclear what you want.  You have a collection of lists of Person objects.  Do you want a separate List tag for each List or all the Person tags to be within one List tag?

Well here's both:

All in one list:

```
XElement items = xdoc.Root
XElement bigList= new XElement("List");
items.Add(bigList);
foreach (ObservableCollection<Person> x in list)
{
    foreach (var person in x)
    {
        XElement person = new XElement("Person",
            new XElement("Name", person.name),
            new XElement("Surname", person.surn),
            new XElement("City", person.city));
        bigList.Add(person);
    }
}
xdoc.Save(path);
```

Individual list for each List:

```
XElement items = xdoc.Root

foreach (ObservableCollection<Person> x in list)
{

    XElement smallList= new XElement("List");
    items.Add(smallList);
    foreach (var person in x)
    {
        XElement person = new XElement("Person",
            new XElement("Name", person.name),
            new XElement("Surname", person.surn),
            new XElement("City", person.city));
        smallList.Add(person);
    }
}
xdoc.Save(path);
```

Comment: I can't add person because, person is not in current context, and I cant do id inside foreach, because I can add several people simultaneously (program logic)

Comment: Don't understand what you mean there. You'll have to explain it a bit better.  The code is doing exactly what you asked it to.  Add a person and add an empty list to the root "items".  You aren't adding anything to the list so it is written out as an empty tag <List />

Comment: I understand that, but I have no idea how to do something like that
<List>
<Person>objects of person</person>
<person>...</person>
</List>
<list><person>...</person></list>

Sometimes in one element of list I have a few pepeole, sometimes only one - and I would like have them in <list> and I have no idea how to do that

Comment: children.Add(person); if I do something like that the xml is empty, returns only <List />

Comment: It looks like that: I have program, where I can add several people at the same time, then in the list I get  several objects in this place, but I can add one person, then I have one object - and that's why i need to have it in <list>

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: You need to describe the structure of the classes and the structure of the xml you want

Answer (score 1):

> It's missing the start of the list

No - it's rendering an *empty* `List` tag . You added `person` to the *root* element instead of to the `children` element, so it gets rendered under the root instead of under `List`.

Comment: if I am doing children.Add(items); it's still the same

Comment: should be `children.Add(person)` within the `foreach`.

Comment: And you are certain that `x` is not empty (meaning you've inspected it in the debugger)?